# Grid in virtual mode with ODBC cursor

Tags: c#, c++, odbc, c++-cli, infragistics

I have an application where we use ODBC to connect to a SQL Server database (don't ask why, is a legacy problem). Everything is working fine when we want to display large datasets (> 1 million records) in a grid. Using the ODBC cursor we can easily navigate back and forth, to the beginning or to the end and show the records is a custom painted grid (Win GDI paint) - everything is written in pure C++.

Now, the boss decided we need a better grid with more features, so we chose the one from Infragistics (using C++/Cli as a bridge between existing C++ code and .NET). Their grid supports virtual mode, but it requires the total number of records that will be read, in our case ODBC doesn't offer such a possibility.

As of now we have 3 solutions

1. Position cursor at the beginning, navigate to the end and count the rows - very slow operation for large datasets.
2. Read all data from ODBC and push into a memory collection then supply needed information to the grid. Again, is slow and very memory consuming.
3. create a `select COUNT(*) from table` and query number of records, it won't work as we have very complicated queries with complex logic inside the select statement which cannot be changed or easily parsed.

Is there a way to have this solved without knowing the total numbers or records? I understand that the vertical scroll won't work properly, but that's fine, users are used to this, as long as they can press `Ctrl + Home`, `Ctrl + End` to go to the first or last record or `Up` and `Down` to navigate between records, they are happy enough.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

thx

Comment: In my view if you are displaying 1M records in a grid then you are doing it wrong in the first place no matter the framework. That being said, native ListView component in a virtual mode handles data very nice.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, I'm not displaying them all at a time, the grid will show only 30 maximum at once, but user should easily jump from row #1 to row #1M, these are the requirements and this is working properly in our custom painted grid.

Comment: How much memory does 1M records consume? Why aren't you loading chunks and using pagination which is the industry standard and arguably the best practice?

Comment: And what would happen if user presses Ctrl-End? Shall I read all data? why doing that if ODBC allows reading row by row only what is actually needed?

Answer (score 0):

You can set LoadStyle of the grid to LoadOnDemand like this:

```
this.ultraGrid1.DisplayLayout.LoadStyle = LoadStyle.LoadOnDemand;
```

However if you perform sorting, filtering, summarizing and etc. the grid will try to load entire data beforehand.
You can also try using WinDataSource - it also supports load data on demand. See this [article](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WinForms/2015.1/CLR4.0/HTML/WinDataSource_Load_Data_on_Demand.html)

Comment: this mode also require me to know the total row count, which I cannot provide.